# No solution with Gekko optimizer in simple case with having several conditions (if2,if3)?

Tags: python, optimization, gekko

community!

I'm working on an applied problem related to battery management with solar panels, and I'm trying to solve it using Gekko optimizer. Here is a reproducible example of my implementation:

```py
import numpy as np
from gekko import gekko as ge

pv_gen = [
    [
        0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
        0.        , 0.21628821, 0.45248806, 0.6605544 , 0.82755066,
        0.94309383, 1.        , 0.99473101, 0.92761446, 0.80282334,
        0.62811655, 0.41435652, 0.1748338 , 0.        , 0.        ,
        0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        
    ],
    [
        0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
        0.        , 0.21628821, 0.45248806, 0.6605544 , 0.82755066,
        0.94309383, 1.        , 0.99473101, 0.92761446, 0.80282334,
        0.62811655, 0.41435652, 0.1748338 , 0.        , 0.        ,
        0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.
    ],

]

load = [
    [
        0.25091601, 0.26052733, 0.25137809, 0.26614229, 0.25835184,
        0.44062643, 0.86531955, 1.        , 0.44139085, 0.25921018,
        0.24908302, 0.26011672, 0.26001465, 0.26010379, 0.26612532,
        0.50450865, 0.5575299 , 0.55895827, 0.74800929, 0.86155478,
        0.74744062, 0.44534278, 0.31157294, 0.25111228
    ],
    [
        0.63107366, 0.62365488, 0.63318315, 0.62548297, 0.63442512,
        0.72115607, 0.94075205, 1.        , 0.72381292, 0.62741716,
        0.63580871, 0.63004974, 0.62598764, 0.62935597, 0.61852053,
        0.74551924, 0.78166073, 0.77483145, 0.87314643, 0.93239358,
        0.86424222, 0.71593412, 0.93499904, 0.62906957
    ],
]

price = [
    0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.12, 0.18, 0.26, 0.18, 0.12,
    0.12, 0.12, 0.12, 0.18, 0.26, 0.18, 0.12, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06,
    0.06, 0.06
]

m = ge(remote=False, name='microgrid')

n_houses = 2
steps = 24

# Variables

# Initializing this way allows to put different ub and lb for each house
battery = [m.Array(f=m.Var, dim=(steps + 1), value=0.1, lb=0.1, ub=0.9) for _ in range(n_houses)] 
action = [m.Array(f=m.Var, dim=(steps), value=0, lb=-0.8, ub=0.8) for _ in range(n_houses)]

net_energy = m.Array(f=m.Var, dim=(n_houses,steps), value=0)
l1_import = m.Array(f=m.Var, dim=(n_houses,steps), value=0, lb=0)
l1_export = m.Array(f=m.Var, dim=(n_houses,steps), value=0, lb=0)

# Parameters

surplus_energy = m.Array(f=m.Var, dim=(n_houses,steps), value=0)
shortage_energy = m.Array(f=m.Var, dim=(n_houses,steps), value=0)
offer = m.Array(f=m.Var, dim=(steps), value=0)
demand = m.Array(f=m.Var, dim=(steps), value=0)
l1_import_rate = m.Array(f=m.Var, dim=(steps), value=0)
l1_export_rate = m.Array(f=m.Var, dim=(steps), value=0)
step_transacted_energy = m.Array(f=m.Var, dim=(steps), value=0)
real_net_energy = m.Array(f=m.Var, dim=(n_houses,steps), value=0)

# Cost function initialization

cost = [m.Array(f=m.Var, dim=steps, value=0) for _ in range(n_houses)]

equations = []

# Define constraints for each variable

for t in range(steps):
    
    # Define offer and demand

    equations.append(offer[t] == m.sum([surplus_energy[house_ix][t] for house_ix in range(n_houses)]))
    equations.append(demand[t] == m.sum([shortage_energy[house_ix][t] for house_ix in range(n_houses)]))

    # Define import and export rates

    baseline = price[t] * (1 - 0.25)
    equations.append(l1_import_rate[t] == m.sum([baseline, 0.001 * demand[t], - 0.001 * offer[t]]))
    equations.append(l1_export_rate[t] == m.sum([l1_import_rate[t], - 0.01]))

    # Transaction contraints

    equations.append(step_transacted_energy[t] == m.if2(condition=(m.sum([offer[t], -demand[t]])), x1=offer[t], x2=deman
d[t]))

    for house_ix in range(n_houses):

        # Constraints to use all the battery energy in the cycle

        equations.append(battery[house_ix][0] == 0.1)
        equations.append(battery[house_ix][steps] == 0.1)

        # Update battery SoC and net energy after action

        equations.append(
            battery[house_ix][t + 1] == m.if3(
                condition = action[house_ix][t],
                x1 = m.sum([battery[house_ix][t], action[house_ix][t] / 0.9 ]),
                x2 = m.sum([battery[house_ix][t], action[house_ix][t] * 0.9 ]),
            )
        )

        equations.append(net_energy[house_ix][t] == m.if3(
            condition = action[house_ix][t],
            x1 = m.sum([load[house_ix][t], -pv_gen[house_ix][t], action[house_ix][t] / 0.9 ]),
            x2 = m.sum([load[house_ix][t], -pv_gen[house_ix][t], action[house_ix][t] * 0.9 ]),
        ))

        equations.append(l1_export[house_ix][t] == m.if3(
            condition=-(offer[t] * demand[t]),
            x1= step_transacted_energy[t] * (surplus_energy[house_ix][t] / offer[t]),
            x2= 0
        ))

        equations.append(l1_import[house_ix][t] == m.if3(
            condition=-(offer[t] * demand[t]),
            x1= step_transacted_energy[t] * (shortage_energy[house_ix][t] / demand[t]),
            x2= 0
        ))
        
        # Define surplus and shortage energy

        equations.append(surplus_energy[house_ix][t] ==  m.max2(-net_energy[house_ix][t],0))
        equations.append(shortage_energy[house_ix][t] == m.max2(net_energy[house_ix][t],0))

        # Cost

        cost[house_ix][t] = m.if3(
            condition=real_net_energy[house_ix][t],
            x1= real_net_energy[house_ix][t] * (price[t] * 0.25) - l1_export[house_ix][t] * l1_export_rate[t] + l1_impor
t[house_ix][t] * l1_import_rate[t],
            x2= real_net_energy[house_ix][t] * (price[t]) + l1_import[house_ix][t] * l1_import_rate[t],
        )

# Define objective function

objs_cost = np.sum(cost, axis=1)

for house_ix, o_c in enumerate(objs_cost):

    m.Minimize(o_c)

m.Equations(equations)

m.options.SOLVER = 1

m.open_folder()

m.solve(disp=True)
```

The logic I want to implement goes as follows:

1. We have two houses with solar panels and batteries. Every timestep, I decide how to charge or discharge (action) the battery within specific ranges.
2. According to the action, if a house's energy balance is positive, it has a shortage; if it is negative, it has a shortage.
3. After an action is applied, houses with a surplus can exchange energy with houses in shortage.
4. Having multiple houses, the offer in a timestep is defined as the sum of the surpluses, and the demand is the sum of the shortages.
5. Exchanging energy between houses is more cost-effective for householders, and the prices depend on the demand and offer.

I tried to present a simplified version with two houses; I think this should have a relatively simple solution, but I might be misunderstanding how to represent the problem with Gekko.

I hope someone can give me a hand to correct my implementation.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See [ask]. Do a preliminary debugging by yourself. And provide a [mre] and debugging details. What is the problem of the current implementation? Did you try to solve a simpler problem with Gekko? What do you mean by ```steps```? Are you trying to do a dynamic simulation? Anyway see [this](https://gekko.readthedocs.io/en/latest/imode.html#dynamics).

Comment: Hi @relent95, I will check the question guidelines to clarify as much as possible my question. The code I put in my minimal reproducible example, you'll find it has no solution if you run it. Steps are time steps. In this case, I optimize energy use throughout the day (24 steps of 1 hour). Regarding the documentation link, I read it, but I think I lack some understanding to know which is the correct configuration for my case. Thanks for your comments!

Comment: Interesting problem.  Are you interested in solutions only in `gekko`?  And on the logic, how would an individual house decide whether to sell an excess or charge its battery?  Or is excess only sold if the battery is full?

Comment: Hi @AirSquid, ideally, the main goal is to use the available energy by charging/discharging the battery optimally. I'm using the optimization case as a baseline to compare with the actions of an agent deciding how to charge or discharge the battery using ML techniques. I am open to trying other alternatives to Gekko too.

Comment: OK.  One of the issues you are going to have to deal with is "knowledge of the future."  If you approach this with optimization, "the math" knows that 7 hours from now, it is gonna get cold and you are going to have to run the furnace and draw a bunch of power and that the sun is obscured so you'll have to draw from battery to save expense, and therefore at present time, you shouldn't sell back any juice.  You might consider a simple rules-based simulation to walk through the time steps with bounds on behavior.

Answer (score 1):

The model has `max2()`, `if2()`, and `if3()` functions that can be challenging for any solver. I recommend using `max3()` and `if3()` as the mixed integer form for all conditional functions because the `max2()` and `if2()` functions rely on MPCCs that have numerical issues near the switch point.

However, there may be another more efficient way to formulate this problem with slack variables. Problem 4 in the [Energy Benchmark set](https://apmonitor.com/do/index.php/Main/EnergyBenchmarks) gives an example that is related to your problem. It uses slack variables to solve the storage and retrieval of energy.

[image: energy storage]

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

m = GEKKO(remote=False)
m.time = np.linspace(0,1,101)

g = m.FV(); g.STATUS = 1 # production
s = m.Var(1e-2, lb=0)    # storage inventory
store = m.Var()          # store energy rate
s_in = m.Var(lb=0)       # store slack variable
recover = m.Var()        # recover energy rate
s_out = m.Var(lb=0)         # recover slack variable
eta = 0.7
d = m.Param(-2*np.sin(2*np.pi*m.time)+10)
m.periodic(s)
m.Equations([g + recover/eta - store >= d,
             g - d == s_out - s_in,
             store == g - d + s_in,
             recover == d - g + s_out,
             s.dt() == store - recover/eta,
             store * recover <= 0])
m.Minimize(g)

m.options.SOLVER   = 1
m.options.IMODE    = 6
m.options.NODES    = 3
m.solve()

plt.figure(figsize=(6,3))
plt.subplot(2,1,1)
plt.plot(m.time,d,'r-',label='Demand')
plt.plot(m.time,g,'b:',label='Prod')
plt.legend(); plt.grid(); plt.xlim([0,1])

plt.subplot(2,1,2)
plt.plot(m.time,s,'k-',label='Storage')
plt.plot(m.time,store,'g--', label='Store Rate')
plt.plot(m.time,recover,'b:', label='Recover Rate')
plt.legend(); plt.grid(); plt.xlim([0,1])
plt.show()
```

This can help as you design the architecture for the optimization problem. Your original problem looks mathematically correct, but it may be too numerically challenging for the solver, especially as you expand to more houses. The slack variable form should be much faster and scale-up better.